# Adding string to the result

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

How can one concatenate string to a result in postgresql? I want to have something like this:

**"lane."+value_+".name"**

in the following query

```
select key_, value_ as "lane."+value_+".name"
from wx_bundlemessage
where char_length(value_)>3
```

so that if value is "fil01", it is returned as "lane.fil01.name"

Comment: It may be worth visiting [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) and searching before posting.

Comment: (not my downvote, though it probably should be)

Answer (score 4):

[PostgreSQL's concatenation operator is `||`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html).

```
'lane' || value || 'name'
```

Note the use of ANSI-style single quoting for literals.

You can't do concatenation in the alias part of the select term, you have to do it in the expression part of `expression AS alias`, e.g.:

```
'lane.'||value_||'.name' AS lane_name
```

The column alias after `AS`, if supplied, must be an identifier constant (unquoted or double quoted). It may not be an expression. So you can't make the alias change based on the field contents.

In future, I strongly suggest [trying to search for the answer first](https://www.google.com/search?q=postgresql+concatenate+string) - the first hit is the PostgreSQL documentation link above.

---

Fancier stuff:

For more complex or longer concatenations you can use `concat`:

```
concat('lane.',value_,'.name')
```

or if joining a long string of delimited values, `array_to_string`:

```
array_to_string(ARRAY['lane', value_, 'name'], '.')
```